# Unable to pause activity. NPE

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

When I use home button or switch to landscape I catch the runtime exception: **Unable to pause activity. NullPointerException.** Help please.

> 01-14 09:23:49.435: E/AndroidRuntime(331): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 01-14
>   09:23:49.435: E/AndroidRuntime(331): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to pause activity
>   {com.example.actiontest/com.example.actiontest.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 01-14 09:23:49.435:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(331):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2354)
>   01-14 09:23:49.435: E/AndroidRuntime(331):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
>   01-14 09:23:49.435: E/AndroidRuntime(331):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2291)
>   01-14 09:23:49.435: E/AndroidRuntime(331):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:117) 01-14
>   09:23:49.435: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:938)
>   01-14 09:23:49.435: E/AndroidRuntime(331):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 01-14
>   09:23:49.435: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 01-14 09:23:49.435:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(331):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 01-14
>   09:23:49.435: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-14
>   09:23:49.435: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 01-14 09:23:49.435:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(331):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   01-14 09:23:49.435: E/AndroidRuntime(331):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 01-14
>   09:23:49.435: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 01-14 09:23:49.435:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(331): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 01-14
>   09:23:49.435: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1576)
>   01-14 09:23:49.435: E/AndroidRuntime(331):    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1617)
>   01-14 09:23:49.435: E/AndroidRuntime(331):    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:481)
>   01-14 09:23:49.435: E/AndroidRuntime(331):    at
>   com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:126)
>   01-14 09:23:49.435: E/AndroidRuntime(331):    at
>   android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1037)
>   01-14 09:23:49.435: E/AndroidRuntime(331):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1181)
>   01-14 09:23:49.435: E/AndroidRuntime(331):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2336)
>   01-14 09:23:49.435: E/AndroidRuntime(331):    ... 12 more

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.actiontest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends    SherlockFragmentActivity 
                          implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        //actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);  

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
        //mSelected.setText("Selected: " + tab.getText());
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
    }
}
```

**TabsPagerAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.actiontest;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new TopRatedFragment();
        case 1:
             // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new TopRatedFragment();
        case 2:
            // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new TopRatedFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 3;
    }

}
```

**TopRatedFragment.java**

```
package com.example.actiontest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class TopRatedFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like error is in SherlockFragmentActivity. Post this class please.

Comment: It's class from ActionBarSherlock library.

Comment: Exception is missing, when I add the following code:

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) { }

But program works not correctly. And I have new warning:

ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `TabsPagerAdapter` extend `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter` and you are good to go.

Comment: You are welcome. Just mark the answer as accepted to let other people, who has the same problem, know that it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Switching to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is not a correct solution. The Android [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) clearly state that

> **FragmentStatePagerAdapter** is more useful when there are a **large** number
>   of pages, working more like a list view. When pages are not visible to
>   the user, their entire fragment may be destroyed, only keeping the
>   saved state of that fragment. This allows the pager to hold on to much
>   less memory associated with each visited page as compared to
>   **FragmentPagerAdapter** at the cost of potentially **more overhead** when
>   switching between pages.

Since, you have only three pages using the `FragmentPagerAdapter` is correct.

Your issue most likely stems from using an old version of `v4` support library. To test if that's the case, just override your `TopRatedFragment#onSaveInstanceState()` method as

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    setUserVisibleHint(true);
}
```

If this fixes your issue then your `v4` support library version has the following bug at `FragmentManagerImpl#saveFragmentBasicState()`

```
if (!f.mUserVisibleHint) {
    /*
    if (result == null) {
        result = new Bundle(); MISSING!
    }*/
    // Only add this if it's not the default value
    result.putBoolean(FragmentManagerImpl.USER_VISIBLE_HINT_TAG, f.mUserVisibleHint);
}
```

which throws a NPE when `result` comes uninitialized but it calls `putBoolean()` still.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not understand. I renamed FragmentStatePagerAdapter to FragmentPagerAdapter and previous exceptions are disappeared. What's happened?

Comment: Because, you perhaps still have your `onSaveInstanceState()` method overridden as you mentioned in your last comment on your question. It probably skips the call to `super.onSaveInstanceState()` and hence skips over the bug too.

Comment: but I removed onSaveInstanceState(). Oh, I created new project and problem has returned. Something wrong with old project.

Comment: Attach the source code to your `v4` support library in Eclipse and then debug after putting a breakpoint just before line number `FragmentManager.java:1576`. That would confirm the issue for sure.

Comment: well, I added onSaveInstanceState and the code works good. Is it normal solution for my problem?

Comment: No. That just proves you're working working with an old `v4` support library. Open Android SDK Manager from Eclipse and check your support library version under Extras. The latest version is `21.0.3`. Update if required and that should fix the bug for good.

Comment: Update the library and test with a new project. You may have to remove the existing `appcompat_v7` project from your workspace. The ADT wizard would create another `appcompat_v7_2` otherwise.

Comment: I don't use appcompat_v7. I removed its folder when added ABS library.

Comment: I'm not sure what the ABS setup is but both `Sherlock` and `v7` depend on `v4` library. If you see your stack trace you'll notice `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 01-14 09:23:49.435: E/AndroidRuntime(331): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1576)` from the `v4` package. Check how ABS references this and patch this library from the one you get after updating through your Android SDK manager.

Comment: I can't update this now. My computer has not internet connection till end of this month. Thank you again.